# React: Filter function case insensitive

Tags: reactjs, filter, case-insensitive

I am filtering with react over a Json file. How can I do a case insensitive search?

This is my code

```
_handleSearch ({ inputNameValue, inputPriceValue }) {
  let list = data.filter(hotel => hotel.name.includes(inputNameValue))
  }
```

Comment: `hotel.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputNameValue.toLowerCase())`?

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot

Comment: Dont do it on each iteration though. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How bout case normalizing both strings, for example lower case them both:
Note that its advised to change the input once outside the filter.

```
_handleSearch ({ inputNameValue, inputPriceValue }) {
  const lowerCased = inputNameValue.toLowerCase();
  let list = data.filter(hotel => hotel.name.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCased ))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just enforce the case:

```
_handleSearch ({ inputNameValue, inputPriceValue }) {
    let list = data.filter(hotel => 
    hotel.name.toUpperCase().includes(inputNameValue.toUpperCase()))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const contacts = [
{
id:1,
name:'khairul Islam',
email:'khairul@gmail.com'
},
{
id:2,
name:'Anisru Rahman',
email:'anisur58@gmail.com'
},
{
id:3,
name:'Raihan',
email:'Raihan@gmail.com'
},
{
id:b,
name:'IB Khalil',
email:'khalil@gmail.com'
}
]

const filterData= 'khairul';


let filterContact = contacts.filter((contact)=>{
                return contact.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterData.toLowerCase()) >=0;
        })
```